# Creating overlay when a new window has been opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, overlay

I am trying to code, or find the code/plugin, to allow for the following scenario to work...

> If there is one link on my page that goes to an external link and it
>   opens a new window for that link, if the user comes back to my site
>   there is an overlay would then be there. This action doesn't even have
>   to happen on a returnto action, but could be one action that when
>   clicked, an overlay is placed while a new window is opened.

**Three things need to happen:**

1. Have just 1 link that will have the unique action/id/class (cannot be every single link)
2. When visitors click on this particular link, a `target="_blank"` or `target="_new"` creates new place for the user to go to, but
3. The original window is not lost so that if the user does come back to the window after step #2 action has taken place, there is now an overlay and message telling them something (i.e., sign-up for a newsletter, thanks for visiting, etc).

***I do not mind if it is a CSS, Javascript, or AJAX fix - I am just having trouble making that happen.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple one. Make sure all the external links have `target="blank"` or `class="external"` in them. And add this HTML in your code:

```
<div class="mask">
  <div class="message"></div>
</div>
```

```
.mask {position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; display: none;}
.mask .message {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
```

And now, the JavaScript part:

```
$(function () {
  // Change ".external" to '[target="_blank"]' for the other way.
  $(".external").click(function () {
    $(".mask").show();
  });
  $(".mask").click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: I do not think I understood you correctly.  When I placed this into a HTML file "as-is" things did not seem to work as planned (http://74.124.198.107/~stackoverflow/overlay-me.html)

Comment: @SlyDawggie Sorry, you didn't add jQuery. Kindly add it by placing this after the title: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I was even able to add a few additional features (cursor change, opacity, etc).  Thanks http://74.124.198.107/~stackoverflow/overlay-me.html

Comment: @SlyDawggie Lemme know if you need more help.